# make: Circular dependency dropped for encrypt&decrypt file

Tags: encryption, makefile, dependencies, circular-dependency

I am creating a makefile to do encrypt & decrypt source file:hello.md. Makefile gives a circular warning but no error.

I wonder if there is anyway to solve the circular dependency in this specific case.

```
CIPHER = enc -aes256
PASSWORD = pass:2942f59899a1e35cb30dafacfe9ac087

ENC = hello.md.enc
DEC = hello.md

enc: $(ENC)
dec: $(DEC)

%.md.enc: %.md
    @echo Encrypt $<
    @openssl $(CIPHER) -e -pass $(PASSWORD) -base64 -in $< -out $@

%.md: %.md.enc
    @echo Decrypt $<
    @openssl $(CIPHER) -d -pass $(PASSWORD) -base64 -in $< -out $@
```

The output for **make enc**:

```
make: Circular hello.md <- hello.md.enc dependency dropped.
Encrypt hello.md
```

The output for **make dec**:

```
make: Circular hello.md.enc <- hello.md dependency dropped.
Decrypt hello.md.enc
```

Comment: Ordinarily, one would choose one form as the more fundamental -- typically based on which you intend to distribute -- and provide only a rule to derive the other.  You don't need a rule for the reverse direction, because the files you would obtain that way are presumed available as a starting point. `make` and the makefile language are not designed or intended for general-purpose scripting.

Comment: More directly: as you have couched the problem, it is inherently circular: you want a makefile that defines both how to build A from B and how to build B from A.  There may be GNUisms that can disguise the inherent circularity, but bringing in sort of thing would make an already bad situation worse.

Comment: Hi John. I though the same as you; however, we could be wrong. But I believe makefile can provide solutions for that. Thanks for you quick reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove this circular dependency message (well, you can edit the source code to GNU make to remove it... for your local use) if both rules are defined.

You can use an if-statement to only declare one rule or the other depending on which target was asked for on the command line.  There are lots of ways to do it; one of them would be:

```
ifeq ($(filter enc,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),enc)
%.md.enc: %.md
        @echo Encrypt $<
        @openssl $(CIPHER) -e -pass $(PASSWORD) -base64 -in $< -out $@
else
%.md: %.md.enc
        @echo Decrypt $<
        @openssl $(CIPHER) -d -pass $(PASSWORD) -base64 -in $< -out $@
endif
```

Comment: MadScientist's solution works. Thanks a lot. As you mentioned a lot of ways to do it. As I am interesting to find how-to, can you share some other ways as well?

Comment: This is not something anyone really does (I don't remember a similar question).  So, there's no how-to that I know of.  But other ways would be variations on the same theme; for example you could put the rules into separate files and use `include` to choose the one you wanted to load, or use recursive `$(MAKE)` invocations, or similar things.  They all have the same result: ensuring only one of the rules is visible in a particular run of make.